# На чистом css сделать плавное открытие меню без привязки к высоте элемента

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том что если задать `height:0; transition 0.3s;`, а потом задать `height: 100%;`, то не произойдет плавного открытия меню.

Comment: используйте height:0; и height: auto;  padding 0; padding 1em 0; например, и тогда плавность будет за счет padding

Comment: Так происходит потому, что `height` [не animatable свойство](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties). Поэтому, можете поставить `height` на `0`, и вместо этого указать `max-height: 0;` а потом задать `max-height: 100%`.

Answer (score 2):

Решением будет воспользоваться контейнером для внутреннего меню. Этому контейнеру мы задаём `overflow:hidden;`, а у внутренних элементов `margitn-top:-высота единичного элемента(с отрицательным значением);`. Либо относительная величина в %. Чтобы меню реагировало на клик - используем невидимый checkbox и помещаем его над схлопывающимся меню, чтобы потом развернуть его, обратившись к нему через ~ (соседний элемент снизу)

```css
.main-menu{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block
}
.sub-menu{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    overflow: hidden
}
input.hidden{
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.sub-menu li{
    transition: 0.8s;
    /*margin-top:-31px;*/
}
.title{
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 40px 0 10px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #555;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    position: relative;
}
.hidden ~ .title::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border: solid 2px #777;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    right: 3px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
.sub-title{
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 40px 0 10px;
    border-top: solid 1px #555;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
.sub-menu li:first-child>.sub-title{
    border-top:none;
}
.hidden:checked ~ .title::after{
    transform: rotate(225deg);
    top: 22px;
}
.hidden:checked ~ .sub-menu>li{
    margin-top:0%;
}
.hidden:not(:checked) ~ .sub-menu li{
    margin-top:-31px!important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li>
    <input class="hidden" type="checkbox" id="switcher-1">
    <label for="switcher-1" class="title">Menu</label>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <input class="hidden" type="checkbox" id="switcher-11">
        <label for="switcher-11" class="title">Menu</label>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
            <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input class="hidden" type="checkbox" id="switcher-12">
        <label for="switcher-12" class="title">Menu</label>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
            <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="hidden" type="checkbox" id="switcher-2">
    <label for="switcher-2" class="title">Menu</label>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="hidden" type="checkbox" id="switcher-3">
    <label for="switcher-3" class="title">Menu</label>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="hidden" type="checkbox" id="switcher-4">
    <label for="switcher-4" class="title">Menu</label>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="hidden" type="checkbox" id="switcher-5">
    <label for="switcher-5" class="title">Menu</label>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sub-title">SubMenu</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```